# Did the "Questons" Button Link at the Top of the Page Change?

Tags: support, status-completed, design

Until around a month ago, when I clicked on the "Questions" option at the top of the Mi Yodeya page, it gave me all questions, unanswered or not, with the most recent ones listed first.   When I do it now, it only lists "Bounty" questions.  Did I accidentially change a setting somewhere/somehow?  Or did the MY site change the "Questions" button's action?

Answer (score 4):

When you click on the Questions link, the page you get shows a set of links above the list of questions -- featured, active, unanswered, etc.  If you click on one of those it filters the view accordingly.

It appears that this selection is sticky; if you select "unanswered", for example (441 at this writing), and then go back to the main site and click "questions" again, you'll see the unanswered ones.  So you probably selected the bounty questions last time you did this; choose "active" (or whatever you like) to change the view.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be in a different tab of the Questions menu. When you click Questions from the main page, just above the listing of questions you should see:

[image: Screenshot of the menu bar from Mi Yodeya's Questions page, with "All Questions" on the left and the menu items listed below on the right]

Newest: the newest asked questions
Featured: questions with current bounties
FAQ: popular historic questions
Votes: questions with the most votes
Active: questions with recent activity (similar to the main page)
Unanswered: questions with no upvoted answers

Comment: Thanks, both of you, that was quick!! ...I retried it, starting at the main page by clicking the MY logo at the middle top of the page....I still never see the newest/featured/etc question page anymore.  I tried Monica's Unanswered suggestion, but no matter whick button I click on beforehand, it still just gives me bounty questions when I hit the Questions button...

Comment: @Gary See my edit.

Comment: NOW I see it...these old eyes...  ..and it IS "sticky" like Monica wrote..now I just get the "newest" ones like I used to...thanks, Folks!